# Adding values using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with the following values

```
street  date    counts
A   2011-01-07  4
B   2011-01-07  2
A   2011-01-08  2
B   2011-01-08  6
```

I want the previous counts by date to be added with the new counts this is the output that I require how could I achieve this in R using dplyr or other libraries.

```
street  date    counts
A   2011-01-07  4
B   2011-01-07  2
A   2011-01-08  6
B   2011-01-08  8
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(street) %>% mutate(counts = cumsum(counts))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   street [2]
#>   street date       counts
#>   <fct>  <fct>       <int>
#> 1 A      2011-01-07      4
#> 2 B      2011-01-07      2
#> 3 A      2011-01-08      6
#> 4 B      2011-01-08      8
```

Comment: Since I already have count for each day, What if I wanted to add data previous month data to current month data?